# Amount of data transferred when doing a gpupdate /force

Tags: group-policy

We are thinking to change the GPO setting - Group Policy refresh interval for users.  (We have it set high and would like to bring it down closer to the default value of 90 minutes).

Management would like to know how much data is actually brought down to a machine.  They are concerned about overloading the network.

For this question, let's assume that the gpo setting "configure registry policy processing" is set to "Process even if the group policy objects have not changed".

We added up packets from a specific DC using wireshark and we came up with 14 megs.
Is there an easier way to check?

Would that be in the range of plausibility?  (I understand that all companies are different and the amount of gpos coming down will be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how many GPOs you have, how complex they are and how many of them are applied to any given computer/user.

You can get an estimation by having a look in the SYSVOL domain share, where GPOs are physically stored.

Comment: Thanks.  If i go and look at the 4 gpos being applied and do a properties, i get a whole 600k.  Should have though of that in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the share size is not really what I'd do as gpupdate does not copy those, but instead checks GPO versions and reads settings from policies that have changed (and only those!)

Do a test: open ncpa.cpL and double-click your NIC. You'll see statistics (bytes received/sent). Now open an elevated command prompt and run gpupdate, then after it finishes, substract the previous bytes received value. Bingo.